# Appcelerator Live video broadcast

Tags: video, appcelerator, live, broadcast

I'm thinking of developing an app that broadcast video to a web and other users can watch the live videos on the web and the app.

The thing is that i do not know how to do it. I have already developed several apps with appcelerator and i would like to use it. So, is there any module, that allows us to broadcast video to a web?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to send the video FROM your app?

Answer (score 0):

Either you try to use WebRTC inside a Webview (e.g. something like https://appr.tc/) or create a module to allow realtime video streaming. By default you can't stream video and I don't see any recent module available on http://gitt.io